# Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on boolean

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on boolean in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/community/MercadoPago/Core/Model/Standard/Payment.php
>   on line 194

At line 194, I have following code

```
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress()->getData();
```

I am kind of new to PHP so don't know what wrong I am doing here.

Comment: `$order->getBillingAddress()` returns a bool. Maybe there is no billing address and it returns false?

Comment: Try printing billing address with just getBillingAddress() $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress(); And see what it returns.

Comment: `if ($addr = $order->getBillingAddress()) { $billingAddress = $addr->getData(); }`